# ^ and $ expressed in fundamental operations in regular expressions

Tags: regex

I've read a book where it states that all fundamental operations in regular expressions are `concatatenation`, `or(|)`, `closure(*)` and `parenthesis` to override default precedence. Every other operation is just a shortcut for one or more fundamental operations.

For example, `(AB)+` shortcut is expanded to `(AB)(AB)*` and `(AB)?` to `(ε | AB)` where `ε` is empty string. First of all, I looked up ASCII table and I am not sure which charcode is designated to empty string. Is it `ASCII 0`?

I'd like to figure out how to express the shortcuts `^` and `$` as in `^AB` or `AB$` expression in the fundamental operations, but I am not sure how to do this. Can you help me out how this is expressed in fundamentals?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36883726/1612432, I remember back from school that we implemented the rules you are mentioning, they, but do not remember how ^ and $ were implemented.

Comment: More info on the topic: [Implementing a Regular Expression Engine](https://deniskyashif.com/implementing-a-regular-expression-engine/), go to the section **ε-NFA**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regular expressions, the way they are defined in mathematics, are actually string *generators*, not search patterns. They are used as a convenient notation for a certain class of sets of strings. (Those sets can contain an infinite number of strings, so enumerating all elements is not practical.)

In a programming context, regexes are usually used as flexible search patterns. In mathematical terms we're saying, "*find a substring of the target string S that is an element of the set generated by regex R*". This substring search is not part of the regex proper; it's like there's a loop around the actual regex engine that tries to match every possible substring against the regex (and stops when it finds a match).

In fundamental regex terms, it's like there's an implicit `.*` added before and after your pattern. When you look at it this way, `^` and `$` simply prevent `.*` from being added at the beginning/end of the regex.

As an aside, regexes (as commonly used in programming) are not actually "regular" in the mathematical sense; i.e. there are many constructs that cannot be translated to the fundamental operations listed above. These include backreferences (`\1`, `\2`, ...), word boundaries (`\b`, `\<`, `\>`), look-ahead/look-behind assertions (`(?= )`, `(?! )`, `(?<= )`, `(?<! )`), and others.

As for ε: It has no character code because the empty string is a string, not a character. Specifically, a string is a sequence of characters, and the empty string contains no characters.

Comment: Thanks. The author of the book also states that running `grep StdIn *.java`will print all lines containing `StdIn`, because `StdIn` is exapnded to `.*StdIn.*`. So in this context `.` actually means all characters but line break, so preping every search term with it should return full lines instead of just search pattern.

Comment: @sanjihan The exact meaning of `.` depends on the regex engine and options you use. In my answer I do use `.` to mean "every character". For `grep` it makes no difference whether `.` matches `\n` or not because the target strings that `grep` matches against are the single lines of the input file; i.e. the target string in `grep` never contains any line breaks in the first place.

Comment: @melpomene Is is possible to code *any* assertion using a "regular", in the mathematical sense, language?

Answer (score 2):

`^AB` can be expressed as `(εAB)` ie an empty string followed by AB and `AB$` can be expressed as `(ABε)` that's AB followed by an empty string.

The empty string is actually defined as `''`, that's a string of 0 length, so has no value in the ASCII table. However the C programming language terminates all strings with the ASCII NULL character, although this is not counted in the length of the string it still must be accounted for when allocating memory.

**EDIT**
As @melpomene pointed out in their comment εAB is equivalent to AB which makes the above invalid. Having talked to a work college I'm no longer sure how to do this or even if it's possible. Hopefully someone can come up with an answer.

Comment: `εAB` is equivalent to `AB`.